# Merging a branch is removing my local branch's newly created files

Tags: git

I am using git for my project and currently I am in branch let's say B. I have added three new files, (file1, file2, file3). Now when I merge another branch (let's say A) to my branch B, it deletes my files (file1, file2, file3).

Comment: Did you add and commit the files before merging the other branch in?

Comment: What you mean by adding? did you commit before merge?

Comment: Sounds like you created branch A from B _after_ you had added those files to the project and that on branch A you _deleted_ them. If so, when merging, git will remove the files.

Comment: If you are using command line, please include the command history so it would be much easy to answer your question

Comment: @RomainValeri I used visual studio to commit those files

Comment: @eftshift0 Branch B parent is X, X parent is Z. Branch A parent is Z.

Comment: @marcelino i used visual studio